# Is apache spark right choice to index bulk amount of data into solr?

Tags: java, apache-spark, solr

We are consuming around 50TB data by making multiple calls to the rest services from a different source and the same data we are planning to index into Apache solr using Apache spark at same time.

If someone can suggest whether Apache Spark is right choice or not for this activity and if yes then which module of spark we should integrate?

Any reference, guidance or suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: I’m pretty sure the bottleneck will be the solr server, not the clients feeding it. How do you expect using Spark will help?

Comment: Lucid work already fixed that bottleneck and code is also open source. you can check [here](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr).

Comment: While we are fetching data by making rest calls from different source, they have some limitations, So my thoughts is,  it won't able to match the spark's speed, and it will not speed up the indexing process. [Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian) What you say?